# mongo aggregation sum of two fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a query where additional fields from lookup are calculated:

```
...    
$addFields: {
    countItems1: {
        $sum: {
             $map: {
                  input: '$lookupedCollection',
                  in: {
                      $size: {$ifNull: ['$$this.arr1', []]}
                  }
             }
        }
    },
    countItems2: {
        $sum: {
             $map: {
                  input: '$lookupedCollection',
                  in: {
                      $size: {$ifNull: ['$$this.arr2', []]}
                  }
             }
        }
    },
    countItems3 : {}
}
```

How do I get countItems3 where countItems3 = countItems1 + countItems2? Thanks for help!

Comment: Use another aggregation step with `$add`: `{$addFields: {countItems3: {$add: ['$countItems1', '$countItems2']}}}`

Comment: Thank you. You can post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: This was probably asked and answered before, so no need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$add two field values in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583999/add-two-field-values-in-mongodb)

Comment: Nearly. In my case, the fields are not numbers, but arrays, the length of which is involved in the calculations. I'm just not strong in mongo queries and was not sure that after the aggregation step the fields were already calculated and the data was known.

Comment: It turns out the aggregation is considered immediately and not at the end?